# How to make a screenshot of last used apps-bar on the left side?

Tags: windows-8

When I touch the left side of the screen at start screen I get the list of all apps I have used last time, but it seems to be impossible to make a screenshot of this list at start screen.

I've tried the following shotcuts:

**<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>**

**<kbd>Print</kbd>**

with no success.

**Edit**: Crazy, but it seems to be possible to make this screenshot if I'm on the classical Windows Desktop

Comment: `Win + Print` saves the screenshot in picture library in folder `Scrrenshot` did you check that?

Comment: @avirk Yes, I have checked, but the screenshots made on modern start screen don't include the left side bar.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oFMPT.jpg are you talking about that?

Comment: @avirk Yes, exactly.

Comment: I'm able to take screenshot of it with `win+print` and `print` as well. Also I tried with **GreenShot** and its really easy for me to get the shot of the left bar.

Comment: @avirk See, my edit. It is possible on the classcal Desktop. Did you try it on the Moder-Ui-Startscreen?

Comment: Well you are right in that case and [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org) will let you help with `Print` button.

Comment: See http://i.imgur.com/OHngr.jpg there.

Comment: @avirk Thank you. A super program. Please post your comment as an aswer, so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: As you said done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) will help you to take screenshot of left bar at start screen with <kbd>Print</kbd> button.